# Browser differences with alexgorbatchev.com syntax highlighter

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting

I am using the syntax highlighter from alexgorbatchev.com on a site in development and in the whole it works really well.

I do have one problem that I just cant seem to solve. My site is not public yet so I will refer to the authors site that shows the same issue.

If you view http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/collapse.html and concentrate on the syntax highlighted line below "Example".

With IE7 then it looks fine.

With Chrome then I get vertical scroll bars showing. I guess it is a CSS issue but I cant work out what it is. ( see http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/screenshot0203201208545.png/ )

How do I get rid of the scroll bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem as well - what I tend to do is add a couple of pixels of padding to the code div. For the example link this would be

```
.syntaxhighlighter {
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
```

This solution always feels like a bit of hack though, but I can't find a better method to get round it.

Comment: @BENBUNCoder np - wish I knew what was causing it though :/